# Canon 5d Mark III: how to switch off the silent shooting mode in the Live View mode?

Tags: live-view, shooting-mode

The problem appeared after the multi-exposure mode was used on the camera (Mark III). At this moment only the silent shooting modes are applied in the Live View mode (i.e. I don't get the "clack clack clack" of the mirror in between shots as it was before; the menu choices (silent/regular) does not affect the shooting modes used by the camera). 
When the shooting via the viewfinder is applied I can choose between the silent (s) and regular shooting modes, and the camera shoots in accordance with the choosing mode.
Thanks.

Comment: In live view mode, the mirror is always up - that's how you get the live view, as the image is sent straight from the sensor to the screen. I've shot with live view on a 5D Mark 2 and Mark 3 for years and it's always been quiet, as both the shutter and mirror are open the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

If you were getting mirror movement when using Live view, it is because you had selected the *Quick Mode AF* which uses the camera's Phase detection AF (normally used when shooting with the viewfinder) instead of the *Live Mode* or *Face detection Live Mode* which use the camera's sensor based Contrast Detection AF.

For instructions in how to select a focus mode in Live View, see page 209 of your *[EOS 5D Mark III Instruction Manual](https://itg.beckman.illinois.edu/visualization_laboratory/equipment/image_capture/manuals/eos5dmkiii-im2-c-en.pdf)*. For how to shoot using the *Quick Mode*, see page 214.