# Why does my shutter makes two sounds?

Tags: nikon, shutter-release, nikon-d3300, sound

I have a Nikon D3300. When I take a photo, it makes one sound than after two seconds, it makes one more sound. This thing irritates me because I can't take photos rapidly and I have to wait for 2-3 seconds for every shot.

Comment: Is the 2-second self-timer on?

Comment: Can you describe the two sounds in more detail? Is it the same sound twice, or are they different?

Comment: Are you using 'live view' to shoot on the screen or are you using the viewfinder?

Comment: Do you have Noise Reduction (dark frame substitution) turned on? That, combined with a very slow shutter speed could be it.

Comment: @cyanos dark frame subtraction wouldn't make a shutter/mirror noise at the very end, the mirror and shutter would reset at the halfway point and remain in place for the entire second exposure.

Comment: The first shutter the shutter opens. The second shutter the shutter closes. I have a similar camera the D5500 and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

*Make sure you don't have live view on.*

Live view is a camera mode where you are able to view the camera's current POV much like the eyepiece, except that you are able to simulate your exposure settings / software optical filters (such as sepia and contrast/white balance enhancement) on screen (assuming your camera has a screen).

If live view is on, you will not able to see through your eyepiece when taking a photo and every time you take a photo, the shutter has to:

- pop out of live-sensor mode, into the eyepiece to start from scratch
- take the photo (pop back to the CMOS sensor for your exposure time).
- quit sensor exposure by popping back to the eyepiece
- snap back to live mode after a couple seconds (*this would be the noise you speak of, kind of like opening to an infinite exposure*)

Live view itself is partly a limiting feature of the camera when it is on in that, you will not be able to take another photo until it "snaps back to live mode". This process takes a few seconds because the camera is still storing to memory the first photo you took, and won't start live mode again until this has completed.

If you are knowingly using live view but still want to take multiple photos quickly, you may be able to use your camera's [`burst mode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_mode_(photography)).

Comment: Is it dark? Sounds to me like the shutter opening for a long exposure, then closing.

Comment: @HelpingHand what's the newest camera you've used with Live View? I've never had to wait for the buffer to completely clear before taking a second photo in Live View.

Comment: I don't think the D3300 *has* to move the mirror twice to take a photo in LV, depending on the focusing method selected. Only if a PDAF method is selected will the mirror need to drop at all. The shutter can reset, open and close, and reopen very quickly without any need for the mirror to move at all if a CDAF method is selected.

Comment: @MichaelClark I don't know the particulars of the D3300 because I'm more of a Canon junky... Are you saying that the camera's shutter is separate from the SLR mirror? ... The only way I can see the camera avoiding moving the shutter/mirror is if the camera is taking a digital readout of the CMOS sensor while in live view (like a point-and-shoot). Then I guess the shutter wouldn't have to move at all.

Comment: @MichaelClark Also, you were asking about the buffer... I have a Canon T3i 600D and, when in live view mode, the camera will not latch the shutter back to live view until the photo is buffered (usually takes 1 to 2 secs). This doesn't bother me as much because I use the eyepiece most of the time...

Comment: The shutters and mirrors in pretty much all modern DSLRs that offer Live VIew are completely separate movements. I'm also a Canon guy. When shooting stills in Live View the mirror normally stays locked up when the shutter curtains do their thing. For a very detailed description of how this works, please see the comments to this answer to a different question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80070/15871

Comment: @HelpingHand WIth some of Canon's cameras that have *Silent Shooting Modes* in Live View only the first curtain moves. It is open for Live View when the shot begins with an electronic curtain and closes in the opposite from normal direction (in the direction it normally moves to reset between frames), the sensor is read out, and then it opens again for Live View. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/69825/15871 and http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38845/15871

Comment: @HelpingHand The last Rebel I've used was before Rebels had Live View, but none of my Canon EOS cameras since have demonstrated that restriction when shooting in Live View. I can continue to take images until the buffer is full whether in Live View or using conventional viewfinder shooting.

Comment: This answer explains the *only* reason the mirror moves when shooting in Live View with a Canon 5DIII: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59987/canon-5d-mark-iii-how-to-switch-off-the-silent-shooting-mode-in-the-live-view-m/60018#60018

Comment: This is useful info!!

Answer (score 5):

It always make two sound (four, to be precise). The first (pair) one is a mirror hitting upper limit (and shutter opening) to free the path to the sensor and the second (pair) one is the mirror hitting the lower limit to reflect the light in the prism (and shutter closing).

If the shutter speed is fast enough you cannot notice these two (four) sounds as individuals but you hear one smash.

If the shutter speed is slow enough, from 1/10 s to bulb, you can distinguish these two (pairs of) souds. Time delay between mirror up and shutter open is imposible to hear.

The reason you cannot shoot faster than frame per 2-3 seconds may be caused by the fact, that you are "collecting the light" for 2-3 seconds. Try to open the apperture, set higher ISO or use flashlight. All this will increase the exposure allowing shorter times/faster shutter speeds.

If you are in full auto, move the selector to P, where you can set exposure and ISO, or to one of A,S,M regimes.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might have the two-second timer enabled. When you press the shutter button the mirror moves up. Then two seconds later the camera takes the picture.

This is a useful feature when shooting from a tripod and using shutter times from around 1 second to 1/100 second when the vibrations from the mirror movement can actually affect the photo. It's also useful if you want to press the shutter button yourself and then move into the frame before the picture is taken.

If you don't want or need to use the two-second timer then turn it off and the camera will take the image as soon as you press the shutter button all the way.